# Newton iteration method

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, numerical-methods, roots

i need some help here.
My function is $f(x) =x^{3}$ . I was asked to find the number of iterations that are needed to reach the precission $10^{-5}$ if $x_{0} = 0.9$

I was wondering if there is a general formula to find the number of iteration, hence, the formula i know is

$$x_{n+1}  = x_{n} - \frac{f(x_{n})}{f'(x_{n})}.$$

I know that it is easy to find the number of iteration by this formula, but what if the number of iteration for reaching my precission is at 40 ? , do i need to calculate all this iterations ? or there is a general formula ?

So please if someone knows please help.

BTW, this is for Newton

Thank you

Comment: I have made a little correction. Check if it is acceptable.

Comment: The recursion should be $x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$.

Comment: @joffysloffy , yes i made a mistake ,  

But still i need a solution to my question

Comment: @HopelessFool ,yes .thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using $f(x)=x^3$ the recursion becomes $x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{x_n^3}{3 x_n^2}=\frac{2}{3}x_n$ and hence can explicitly be solved as

$$ x_n = \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n x_0.$$

Now you just have to plug this into the inequality $x_n\leq 10^{-5}$, take the logarithm and solve for $n$, which gives

$$n\ln\frac{2}{3}\leq\ln\frac{10^{-5}}{0.9}\quad\Rightarrow\quad n\geq\frac{\ln (10^{-5}/0.9)}{\ln(2/3)}\approx 28.2$$
Note that $\leq$ turns to $\geq$ as you divide through a negative logarithm.

This means, the 29th iteration is the first one to be inside the $10^{-5}$-neighborhood.

Comment: Oh , I see now . Thank you so much!

Comment: I am getting the answer in 23-rd iteration, by practical computation?

Comment: @HopelessFool I made a computation which agrees, giving $n=29$, my results are $[x_0,x_1,x_2,...,x_{28},x_{29}]=[0.9,0.6,0.5,...,0.00001056,0.00000704]$. You might check your code and the initial condition $x_0$.

Comment: @flonk Thank you. Yes it is exactly 29. after correction I am getting it.

Answer (score 3):

Ingeneral the [error in Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Proof_of_quadratic_convergence_for_Newton.27s_iterative_method) satisfies:

$$e_{n+1}=-\frac{f''(\theta_n)}{2f'(x_n)}e_n^2$$

where $\theta_n$ is certain number between $x_n$ and the root.

Put $e_0$ equal to the length of the interval where your root is. Assume you can bound $$|-\frac{f''(\theta_n)}{2f'(x_n)}|<M.$$

Then $$|e_n|\le M|e_{n-1}|^2\le M^{1+2}|e_{n-2}|^4\le ...\le M^{1+2+4+...+2^n}|e_0|^{2^n}=|e_0M|^{2^{n}}M^2$$.

If we want $d$ digits we can put $|e_0M|^{2^{n}}M^2<10^{-d}$ and solve for $n$.

We get ${2^{n}}>\frac{\ln(\frac{10^{-d}}{M^2})}{\ln|e_0M|}$. So

$$n>\log_2\left(\frac{\ln(\frac{10^{-d}}{M^2})}{\ln|e_0M|}\right).$$

Comment: For this situation $f(x)=x^3$ and $0< \theta_n< x_n < 1$ we have $|f''(\theta_n)/(2f'(x_n))|=\theta_n/x_n^2$. What could be an upper bound $M$ independent of $n$ if $x_n\to 0$?

Comment: @ABC , Thank you to you too .!

Comment: @flonk In order to have this estimation you need to "assume $\frac{|f''(x)|}{|f'(x)|}$ bounded in the interval". The reason you can use your estimation without this condition is because you know, and you are using it, what the root is.

Comment: @ABC my point is that this assumption is invalid and your result cannot be used, as $M$ does not exist.

Comment: @flonk Your point is that you don't know much what you are talking about. This argument is used in *general* applications, when you don't know what the root is, but you can ensure that $|f''(x)/f'(x)|$ is bounded in the interval where the root is going to be searched. "Invalid", What a nerve! Read the assumptions first. The bound doesn't solve the exercise $f(x)=x^3$ but that case you know the root already. In a general problem let us see what you can do.

Comment: @ABC I do fully understand that your approach can be used if the root is unknown. But your case of bounded $|f′′(x)/f′(x)|$ does just not meet the situation of the question, which just puzzled me for a moment, sorry, no reason to panic ...